# Virtual Machine Suddenly slows down

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I have a windows 10 home virtual machine running on a linux mint Lenovo z70. It runs super well, until at some point it always drops so that *anything* takes like 5 minutes to work, eventually the whole thing freezes. Reverting back to a previous snapshot fixes it, but why is it doing this? I'm installing no software just testing batch coding and testing my wix websites on edge. It looks like windows search is writing to disk a lot.

Comment: Are you running out of memory in the VM?

Comment: I set it to be dynamic I believe. I’ll check next time I can.

Comment: So it could be reading/writing to the swap file on disk ...